# Making GridView sortable when manually asigning DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that I would like to have sortable.  When I define it like this:

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="gridview" DataSourceID="GridDataSource" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" >
```

The sorting works just fine.  ie. when I click the column header the grid sorts by that column.

But when I define it like this:

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="gridview"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" >
```

and in codebehind:

```
GridView1.DataSource = GridDataSource;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Using the latter method the sorting does not work. The column headers are links but the grid does not order itself.

I'm setting the DataSource after the page load so the user can chose from some filters (dropdown lists) to restrict the records returned.

Can someone tell me how to set the datasource in codebehind and get sorting functioning?  Alternatively a good way to stop the grid from databinding on initial page load.

Comment: You might find your answer in [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388245/gridview-sorting-works-once-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get automatic sorting on an [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) [gridview](/questions/tagged/gridview) you'll need a few things.

First, you'll have to set `AllowSorting="True"` on the gridview tag, which you did.

Second, you'll need to configure your `Fields` correctly.  Since you have `AutoGenerateColumns=false` you'll need to manually specify the [SortExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfield.sortexpression(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<asp:BoundFiled DataFiled="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
```

Third, you'll need to make sure your data source supports sorting.  If you data bind directly to a [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx) you should get support out of box.  However, if you are binding to a [objectdatasource](/questions/tagged/objectdatasource) or [sqldatasource](/questions/tagged/sqldatasource) you'll need to ensure that your `SelectMethod` supports sorting.

For example, for an [objectdatasource](/questions/tagged/objectdatasource) you'll need to set the [SortParameterName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.sortparametername(v=vs.110).aspx) and then ensure that same parameter is present in the [SelectParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.selectparameters(v=vs.110).aspx) collection:

```
 <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="GridDataSource" runat="server"
    SelectMethod="ExampleSelect"
    TypeName="SO"        
    SortParameterName="sortExpression">       
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="sortExpression" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
 </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Then the `SelectMethod` will be responsible for implementing the sorting:

```
 namesapce SO{
     public class ExampleSelect{
         public object[] ExampleSelect(string sortExpression)
         {
            var allItems = GetAllItems();

            bool sortDesc = 
                 //if sort descending, sortExpression will be suffixed with " DESC"
                 (sortExpression.Split(' ').Count() > 1);

            if (sortExpression.StartsWith("Name"))
            {
                if (sortDesc)
                    return allItems.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name);
                else
                    return allItems.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
            }
            else
            {
               return allItems;
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

**Tips**

- For a sexier way to build up dynamic sort linq expressions, see this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/233505/1224069
- Scott Mitchell has a fantastic tutorial fully exploring databinding with sorting and pagination available on MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404876.aspx

**Databinding in code_behind**

I recommend data binding declaratively in markup using one of the datasource controls.  It gets rid of misc code in the code behind and lets the framework deal with when to databind so you don't have to bust out the `if (!IsPostBack)` statements.

Comment: I tried this but the datasource function is not called when I click to order the grid - so the "sortExpression" doesn't do anything.  I'm sure you are correct in everything you said but I'm definitely missing something.

Comment: Can you update the question with your select method and your object data source declaration

Comment: I've been tidying the code massively and as a result this now works using your solution.

Comment: I have a datasoure called "GridDataSource" and after backtracking a  little bit I realized that I had changed one line from  `GridView1.DataSource = GridDataSource;`  TO  `GridView1.DataSourceID = "GridDataSource";`  That seems to make all the difference.

Comment: Yes, that will do it!  Setting `DataSourceID` tells the GridView to use a specific control.  Setting `DataSource` to "GridDataSource" will bind your GridView to a string.